# Want to create a regression line with lines for 2SD above the mean - SPSS

Tags: regression, spss, standard-deviation, linear

I am using SPSS to do a linear regression for some data. I am able to get a line of best fit and able to get the 95%CI lines but I wanted to see if it is possible to get lines for 2SD (above and below the mean).

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

Also, is it possible to plot 2 sets of data on a linear regression plot with best line of fit etc? The independent variable is age and dependent variable is height however, what makes the 2 sets of data different is an intervention such as "nutrition" etc.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to get +/- X SD lines. How exactly those would be computed isn't clear to me. If you mean lines at so many standard errors, those aren't directly available, though they could be fudged by using prediction intervals based on a bit of arithmetic to specify the coverage level corresponding to that many SEs.

It is possible to plot two or more sets of data with fitted lines and to add mean or individual prediction intervals for them. If you have your groups or sets of points defined by a variable in your dataset:

- Click on Graphs>Chart Builder. Under Gallery, look in the Choose from list for Scatter/Dot and click on that.
- Select the Grouped Scatter option from the tiles below the canvas area (the third one from the left). Specify the variables for the X and Y axes, then move your grouping variable to the Set Color box.
- On the right, under Element Properties, at the bottom check the Subgroups box in the Linear Fit Lines section. Then click OK.

That will the grouped scatterplot with fit lines for each group. To add the prediction intervals:

- Double-click on the chart to activate it.
- Single-click on one of the fitted lines. This should highlight both/all of them and bring up a Properties box on the right.
- In the Properties box select the Fit Line tab.
- In the Confidence Intervals section at the bottom, select Mean or Individual, and if you want something other than 95% intervals, change that number. Click Apply.